# Ranking high on Google - Appropriate method to get thousands of detail pages ranked in Google?

Tags: seo

I have thousands of unique item detail pages that I would like to get spidered / linked to off our homepage. I saw great success by linking to several hundred of these item detail pages (from the homepage) BUT there is no way I can put thousands (10K+) of links to all the item detail pages.

- The item detail pages live on one of the sites.
- I then have 3 other topics related sites that I can pull in links from.
- So a total of 4 sites, but only one has the item detail pages.

**My question is:**

From an SEO perspective what is the best way programatically to link to these item detail pages from the homepage of all 4 websites? Keep in mind only one of the 4 sites contains the item detail pages.

My strategy is to break the thousands of links up into directory pages that I then link to from the homepage. The directory pages would break the links up into static 500 or less links on each SEO friendly static pages.

Has anyone had a similar challenge, and how did you code it? I do also use Google Webmaster Tools to submit sitemaps of these pages.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do a couple of things-

(1) Keep unique title/meta tags for each of the detail pages... This is very important... duplication of these fields can lead to drastic reduction in rankings. Maybe you can create a script that uses some data from within each detail page, to set that page's title/meta keywords/meta description.

(2) Also if you plan to make title of the format "Detail page title + website title" then keep website title at the end (not at the beginning) - only if your website title contains any/some of the keywords for which you want to rank, only then you should keep the overall site title at the beginning. (This is because search engines measure keyword prominence, which roughly translates to how prominently a word is being shown in a phrase- the nearer that word is to the beginning of the phrase, the higher is the keyword prominence of the word in that phrase)

(3) Google generally lowers the rank value of a web page, once it finds more than 150 links on that page... This is a general estimate... I suggest that instead of keeping 500 links per page, you keep only 150 links.

(4) Read up some articles on pagination- there are newer ways to clearly tell search engines about different pages which contain different sections of the same data (in this case the data being the entire list of detail pages)... I cant tell you offhand, but I think you can use those methods to clearly tell Google about how your site's list of detail pages is split up. Refer http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2109932/Google-Introduces-New-Pagination-Tags-Pushes-View-All-Pages. Note that Google is pushing for a "View All" page (ie single page containing all the individual pages data) but I think you should not do that, as then the total number of pages will go up...Google does say that in some cases, eg page load for entire data in single page is too slow, in such cases you can create page-wise data and not create a single page containing the entire data (although Google prefers a single page containing entire data).

I think the above should take care of it, although I have to warn you beforehand that although I know the above from theory, but in practice I have never had the chance to implement such a scenario.

Comment: Thats an interesting read Arvind, thanks! Google once stated pages should 100 links or less but they have since clarified that more - http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/how-many-links-per-page.